# Encoding Japanese characters

Tags: python, encoding

How would I encode the following:

```
chapter_mapping = {'chapter': ' チャプター'}
```

so I can call `chapter_mapping['chapter']`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `unicode` literals.

```
chapter_mapping = {'chapter': u' チャプター'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to add a header to your file in python 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
chapter_mapping = {'chapter': u'チャプター'}
```